# How to change commit on main branch (create model AbstractCard) so that other commits don't leave (graph does not change)

Tags: git

I try change commit(create model AbstractCard) and rebase for VisaCard, but other commits (visa_gold, visa_classic) don't rebase.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of merging you could fetch the latest changes and then perform a `rebase` Then you would not get any merge commits and the graph would be a straight line.

Comment: https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#imperative  See point 5.